# mini-profiler drop some steps

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm starting to use Stackoverflow MiniProfiler on my ASP MVC 4 web application.
I've put only the Start and Stop calls in BeginRequest and EndRequest respectively.
I've add to one action some steps like so:

```
private ActionResult MyAction(string id)
{
  using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("GatherReportItems")) {
    ...
  }

  using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("BuildReportViewModel")) {
    ...
  }

  using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("AddingExtraInfo")) {
    ...
  }
}
```

The problem is that on the first request to that action I can see all 3 steps, on any further request I see only the first step and not any of the others.

When I debug my application I can see inside MiniProfiler.Current -> Head -> Children that all the 3 steps are there. It is in the client display (after clicking on the timing box) that I can see only part of the steps.

Comment: Is it possible that the client side does not display those steps because they are very very short, 2 and 3 ms ?

Answer (score 3):

I've now notice that there is a small link name **show trivial** at the bottom of the profiling details popup which add the very short timings